# GNU make - what is "could not be stat'd"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I executed `make all --print-data-base` and I see many lines containing:

> ...could not be stat'd

What is that?

Comment: `stat()` gets meta-information about a file: inode data, atime/ctime/mtime, etc... could not be stat'd means either "file doesn't exist" or maybe "access denied". e.g. "you tried to stat() file X, and I couldn't get any information about it, so maybe it doesn't exist"

Comment: your command to to print data base catches all, and some of the files are not of the type to return specific information as requested, so such files return a null because of invalid type: meaning no information of such files; not an error just a debugging concept.

Comment: @OlaB ok. Put that as the answer.

Comment: ok thanks! glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your command to to print data base catches all, and some of the files are not of the type to return specific information as requested, so such files return a null because of invalid type: meaning no information of such files; not an error just a debugging concept